# HttpURLConnection hangs (freezes) with wrong credentials

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

my application wants to check whether the user's login credentials are valid to access the web API.
To do so, I have implemented this with AsyncTask method.

Here is doInBackground() implementation.

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
            Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication (user, password.toCharArray());
                }
            });

            return (HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        } catch (IOException e){
        }
        return false;
    }
```

When I enter the right user credentials, it would work fine. However, when I enter the wrong credentials, it would stay hanging at urlConnection.getResponseCode() (does not throw any exception).
I tried to add urlConnection.connect() in between, but I found no success.
I have internet access set up in manifest.

Comment: have you checked that the server properly handles incorrect credentials? (ex. returning an error response)

Comment: @ginomempin When I cURL the api data with incorrect credentials, instead of getting JSON value, it returns html code -> <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /webapi/v1/hosts. Reason:
<pre>    Unauthorized</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>

Comment: first off, i think your request method should be **POST**. next, my guess is that's the old issue with `Authenticator` (which I recommend to avoid using). try putting your username,password credentials directly into the HTTP request property as answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14572099/2745495) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16359106/2745495).